# Вопрос по железу Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

У меня стоит Mac OSX Hig Sierra 10.13.16 maсbook pro 2011года c Xcode 10.1 дальше не обновляется. 
Вопрос если я программирую на проекте а у коллеги стоит Catalin и Xcode 11.3. Как он коллега должен скомпилировать (собрать проект) чтоб я тоже мог программировать в этом проекте?  Т.е если он в podfile соберет проект со swift 4.2

```
 post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
     end
 end
end
```

Будет ли у меня такой проект собираться? Не лучше ли использовать Carthage?
Какую платформу лучше использовать в pod ios 8 нормально.
И вопрос по подам например Alamofire какую версию собирать чтоб у него и у меня все работало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, нужно переходить на Xcode 11:

> Starting April 2020, all new apps and app updates will need to be
>   built with iOS 13 SDK

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09102019a